# Import/Export data in CSV format, stored in Core data via email

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on an app which is extensively based on Core data. I got several entities and relationships. The format is kinda like this -

There is an entity "CARDS" which has one to many relationship with "RECIPIENTS" (another entity) and "CUSTOMERS" (another entity). The recipients and customers can be added/modified/deleted by the user. The list is stored in a table view.

I want to do an export of that data (recipient, customers etc.) via email. But all that is stored in Core data right? So Do I have to store that in documents directory somewhere or get the path to where it is stored in core data?

I followed these links but they don't use core data as such to store the data, will the logic be the same as shown in the link below: -

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Convert the DB to CSV (NSData) attach it to an email.

Comment: What is the purpose of the export (why CSV)?

Comment: @JustinMeiners How to do that?

Comment: @Wain Ok, not CSV, then like in the link they had exported in .sbz. I wanted to know how to accomplish this?

Comment: But why? Backup / sharing ? What is the recipient going to do with it? Can you just send the .sqlite file?

Comment: @Wain that's the requirement. Like sharing the file to iTunes and exporting it via email to share between users. I just don't know how to do that ? I am figuring out by seeing tutorials. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You specify the path to the .sqlite file when you create the store. You can copy that file (using `NSFileManager`) to another location and rename it (to change the extension to some custom value that is specific to your app). Once you have moved it, if you moved it to the correct folder it will automatically be available to iTunes sharing. Or, you can get the data for the file (using `dataWithContentsOfFile:`) and then add that as an attachment to an e-mail (again, specify a file extension for the attachment that is specific to your app).

You then want to look at teaching your app to handle that file extension to allow importing (see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)).

Comment: thanks for answering to that. I will follow what you said. So the links I mentioned are of No help here?

Comment: They are useful if they cover what you want to do. The first gives details of iTunes sharing and covers some things you want to do to import from there and where to put files so they can be exported that way. Basically all I'm saying is to copy the .sqlite file with a different name rather then bothering to export the file to some other format